# block device access on windows docker tool box

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, boot2docker, block-device

docker installed my machine

> 1. ubuntu 12.04 (Virtual Machine on MAC)
> 2. windows 7    (native)

and Docker images as below ..

> ubuntu 12.04 base docker image

when i run Docker image on Ubuntu 12.04 and insert Micro SD Card then Docker Image can access this block device.

Docker Image Execution Command as ...

> docker run --privileged -i -t --cidfile ${ID_FILE} $1

and input lsblk command (on docker image)result as ..

> root@4373a704da4a:/# lsblk
>
> NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
>
> sda      8:0    0    64G  0 disk
>
> |-sda1   8:1    0    63G  0 part
>
> |-sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part
>
> `-sda5   8:5    0  1022M  0 part [SWAP]
>
> sdb      8:16   1   3.8G  0 disk
>
> `-sdb1   8:17   1   3.8G  0 part
>
> sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
>
> sr1     11:1    1  1024M  0 rom

sdb is Micro SD Card.

but when i tired this on Windows docker toolbox (same image above) sd card not appears.

docker image which executed by windows 7 and docker toolbox can's access block device ?

thank you.

Comment: docker execution command is
> docker run --privileged -i -t --cidfile "cidfilename"  "docker_Image_Name"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

windows Docker environment is based on "virtual box"

so, for using USB, install virtual box extension and setting USB 3.0 driver enable.

and run docker container, able access to Micro SD Card /dev/sdx